# Java method that writes to file does nothing when invoked from a JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Hey, all! I have a class method who's primary function is to get a Map object, which works fine; however, it's an expensive operation that doesn't need to be done every time, so I'd like to have the results stored in an XML file using JAXB, to be read from for the majority of calls and updated infrequently.

When I run a class that calls it out of NetBeans the file is created no problem with exactly what I want -- but when I have my JSP call the method nothing happens whatsoever, even though the rest of the information is passed normally. I have the feeling it's somehow lacking write privileges, but the file is just in the root directory so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for the help!

The code looks roughly like this:

```
public class DataHandler() {

    ...

    public void config() {
        MapHolder bucket = new MapHolder();
        MapExporter exp = new MapExporter();

        Map map = makeMap();
        bucket.setMap(map);
        exp.exportMap(bucket);
    }
}
```

And then the JSP has a javabean of Datahandler, and this line:

```
databean.config();
```

It's probably a tad more fragmented than it needs to be; the whole bucket rigamarole was because I was stumbling trying to learn how to write a map to an xml file. Mapholder is just a class that I wrap around the map, and MapExporter just uses a JAXB marshaller, and it all does work properly when run from NetBeans.

Comment: check your logs, if it's a permissions issue, it should show up there.. do you get an error or something in the console or logs?

Comment: Nothing turns up in the glassfish logs, is there somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK turns out I'm just dumb; everything *was* working fine, the file was just being stored in a folder at the localhost location. Whoops! That'd be my inexperience with web development at work.

Comment: Sorry, I just got back to my desk. That was going to me by next question :) (did you check the localhost's root folder? did you do a search for the file in the system?) -Glad you sorted it out

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help anyways xD I did think it was really weird that no errors were turning up anywhere.